# How can i get javascript variable to store in php?

Tags: javascript, php

i see one example in which they pass javascript variable into php by like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var q = "hello";
    <?php
      $ff ="<script>document.write(q1)</script>";
   ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $ff; ?>
<input type="hidden" value="nis" id="val">
</body>
</html>
```

i try one exaple like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var q = $("#val").val();
    <?php
      $ff ="<script>document.write(q)</script>";
   ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $ff; ?>
<input type="hidden" value="nis" id="val">
</body>
</html>
```

but its not give output. there is any solution for this problem? how can i get value in php variable? i want "nis" in $ff variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Pl. try this code   
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var q=document.getElementById("val").value;
        //document.write(q);

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>



    <input type="hidden" value="nis" id="val"></body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var q=document.getElementById("val").value;
        document.write(q);

    </script>
     <?php
          echo $ff="<script type='text/javascript'>
                    document.write(q)</script>";
       ?>
    <?php echo $ff; ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you.. it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass Javascript variable to PHP variable as PHP is server side language and Javascript is client side.
Please check this answer

[How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

[What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: there is any solution for passing javascript value on same page?

Comment: As far as I know,on current page it is not possible.

Comment: You can self submit the form which will result in page refresh and then you can store the value in PHP variable

Comment: You can also make use of AJAX for this.

Comment: can you give ajax solution for this?

Comment: are you processing this values and doing some operations on it? It depends on what your are trying to achieve as whether to make an AJAX request or not

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var abcd = "xyz";
</script>

<?php
echo "<script>document.write(abcd);</script>";
?>
```

Comment: it will echo but when you put it into variable and do calculations it will fail.

Comment: Then pass javascript variable using ajax calll to the respective we Page in php and do whatever you wish.alternative

Comment: best way is to use of ajax and get method.